# OneTimeTearDown is not working using selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, nunit

This code should takes a screenshot when test fail:

```
 [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TestFail()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        if (NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Success)
        {
            string screensLocation = @"D:\";
            string testName = NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
            var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(screensLocation + testName + ".png");
        }
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // my code, here test is failed
    }
}
```

But it is not working. I don't have any screen in location D:\
Otherwise is there a way to debug code under OneTimeTearDown Attribute? Because when the test is fail, debugging ends and I don't know what's going on in the method TestFail().
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This may be permission issue, please start VisualStudio in Administrator mode (with elevated permission) and try in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneTimeTearDownAttribute` is a feature of NUnit.

Although your tag says "nunit", your code is not actually using it. `TestClassAttribute` and `TestMethodAttribute` are features of MS Test. If you tried to run this test with NUnit, it would not recognize the tests at all.

Obviously, your test assembly does reference the NUnit framework, since it would not otherwise compile.

So... bottom line, your test code references two different frameworks in such a way that it cannot be run successfully by either runner!!! You have to choose which of the two you want to use, remove the other reference and use a runner for the framework you choose to keep.